Seasonal decompose with statsmodels.tsa.seasonal
Could you help me understand the result of a seasonal decompose with
statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL?
I'm playing around with this for the first time after reading an article that uses it on the side, and trying to get a better understanding of how it works and how I can get closer to the result I expect.
I would expect -

The trend graph values to be 0.
The seasonal7 graph to go from 1-7 periodically.
The seasonal13 graph to go from 1-13 periodically.
The residual graph values should be 0.

I just realized that the trend + the seasonality graphs + the residuals should result in the observed values.
So I guess my expectations are generally justified but the trend analysis messes up the analysis since there is no trend in my series?
And the result is considere good enough because the residuals are lower than 1% or some such criterion, so the algorithm does not try to improve on it?
